# convert int to BigInteger

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using `uniqueresult()` method present in the `org.hibernate.Query` class whose return type is `Object`.

In my case i am holding this result in `BigDecimal` class. Now, this is  throwing `ClassCastException ( java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer)`.

I tried with `BigInteger` also, same kind of exception.

Can you please help on  how to cast this kind of result.

Comment: BigDecimal != BigInteger and no amount of casting will change that. If you want to convert an BigDecimal to an Integer value you have to actually convert it by calling the `.intValue()` method on BigDecimal

Comment: And both are != Integer. So the question: why does it return integer and why do you want to cast it to BigDecimal (or BigInteger)?

Comment: the result is too large, Integer can not hold that much records.

Comment: Then you obviously need to find out why that query returns Integer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to obtain BigDecimal from an Integer you have to do that:

```
BigDecimal myBigDecimalValue = new BigDecimal("" + myIntegerValue);
```